# ffmpeg overlay timstamp over video

Tags: linux, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay timstamp over video using below command

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-B.ttf: fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow: text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1507046400\:%d-%m-%Y %T}'" output.mp4
```

But getting error like

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x1999d00] %{pts} requires at most 2 arguments
```

My ffmpeg version is `ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

The output video is written but no timestamp over video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ffmpeg version (2.8.) is ancient in terms of functionality. It does not support that text expansion feature, which was introduced in 3.0.0.

Upgrade to a newer one, e.g. by downloading a static build from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html.